# What is the benefit of WTP

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp

Is it beneficial to have WTP? Which features are most useful?

Comment: Could I ask: what's WTP? [Googling "define:WTP"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define:WTP) didn't offer any (valid) explanations, so far as I could tell...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WTP stands for Eclipse Web Tools Platform. It adds support for Java EE development, such as writing web apps (using JSP, JSF, etc.), writing EJBs and writing Java web services. It also includes tools to allow deploying your app to a Java application servers, such as WebLogic, JBoss, Tomcat, etc.

WTP also includes XML and JavaScript tooling that might be useful even if you don't intend to do any Java EE development.

Answer (score 1):

If you need, it is, depends what do you do.  WTP includes source and graphical editors, wizards and built-in applications to simplify development, also there are tools and APIs to support deploying, running etc...

I found this until search for mroe features:
[WTP 3.0 Java EE 5 and Web Services Features](http://live.eclipse.org/node/572)

Answer (score 1):

For me , the most useful feature of WTP is that it allows me to deploy my web application to the web container quickly in the development environment . Together with the hot-deploy feature of the web container , if I modify the web resources (eg .html, jsf,jsp ,css, ..) and the java classes files , these changes will be deployed and will take effect immediately without the need to restart the web container.

It largely shorten the development time as I can validate my changes by just refreshing the browser , without waiting for the server to restart and re-deploy the whole application due to the only small changes.

This link http://ducquoc.wordpress.com/2010/11/06/eclipse-wtp-tomcat-hot-deploy/ shares how to do hot-deploy to the Tomcat using the WTP.